# how to make an element still active be kept active even after refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using this code to active Current Element. I found this code on "w3schools.com". in this code, If I refresh, the currently active element disappears. How can the element that is still active be kept active even after refresh?.

```js
// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var header = document.getElementById("myDIV");
var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

```css
/* Style the buttons */

.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
}


/* Style the active class, and buttons on mouse-over */

.active,
.btn:hover {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>Active Button</h1>
<p>Highlight the active/current (pressed) button.</p>

<div id="myDIV">
  <button class="btn">1</button>
  <button class="btn active">2</button>
  <button class="btn">3</button>
  <button class="btn">4</button>
  <button class="btn">5</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You could try to use [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) (a storage that won't diseappear even if you close/reopen the browser) or [session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) A storage that clear every time you close the window

Comment: @polypode ,  I'm a beginner in this field. I don't know about local or session storage. what would I do?

Comment: Well, I would do that like so : give an unique id to each button, add an event listener to every one of them. On click, switch the state of the button and save it in the local storage (`localStorage.setItem(buttonId, buttonState)`). And then, on page load, I'll loop through the keys of localStorage and re-apply the last state of each button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved your problem, try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
/* Style the buttons */
.btn {
border: none;
outline: none;
padding: 10px 16px;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 18px;
}

/* Style the active class, and buttons on mouse-over */
.active, .btn:hover {
background-color: #666;
color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Active Button</h1>
<p>Highlight the active/current (pressed) button.</p>

<div id="myDIV">
<button class="btn">1</button>
<button class="btn active">2</button>
<button class="btn">3</button>
<button class="btn">4</button>
<button class="btn">5</button>
</div>

<script>


 var header = document.getElementById("myDIV");
 var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("btn");

for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
     btns[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
        var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
        current[0].classList.remove('active');
        this.classList.add('active');
        var array = [];
        array.push(btns);
        localStorage.setItem('element', this.innerText);
     });
}

    function setActivatedItem(){
        var item = localStorage.getItem('element');

        if(item){
            for (var a = 0; a < btns.length; a++) {
                if(btns[a].innerText == item){
                    btns[a].classList.add('active');
                }else{
                    btns[a].classList.remove('active');
                }
            }
        }
    }

    window.onload == setActivatedItem();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think sessionStorage is better than localstorage. thanks for the solution.

Comment: sessionStorage is similar to localStorage; the difference is that while data in localStorage doesn't expire, data in sessionStorage is cleared when the page session ends.